# Returning an array with the largest number from each sub-array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Hey fellow programmers,

I'll get right to it, as you've guessed from the title, I want to return an array consisting of all the largest numbers from each sub array. I have the correct code. However, there's one line of the code I do not understand. I used the hints from freecodecamp.
The line I don't understand is commented out //this is the line I don't understand. In particular, the [0] on arr[i][0]. Whats the purpose of the [0]. When I take it out to see the displayed results on the console, it returns the array as is, instead of an array with all the largest numbers from each sub-array.

Thanks,

```
function myFunc(arr) {
    var resultArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var largstNumInEach = arr[i][0]; //this is the line i dont understand.
        for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            if(arr[i][j] > largstNumInEach) {
                largstNumInEach = arr[i][j]
            }
        }
        resultArray[i] = largstNumInEach;
   }

   return resultArray;
}

var list = myFunc([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], 
[1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);

console.log(list);
```

Comment: Cause you log `resultArray` ? Maybe just log `largestNumInEach` to see what it is?

Comment: You can also use `list.map(a => Math.max(...a))`

Comment: `var largstNumInEach = arr[i][0];` It is just first element to compare with the others. But also you need to start next loop from 1,`for (var j = 1;` to avoid extra operations

Answer (score 0):

It will get the element from the 0th index. This is how it will work .

This line `for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {` will iterate over this array.

```
[[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]
```

which again consist of sub arrays.

So at one point `arr[i]` will be `[4, 5, 1, 3]`,`[13, 27, 18, 26]`....

So when `i=0` `arr[i]` will be `[4, 5, 1, 3]` when `i=1` `arr[i]` will be `[13, 27, 18, 26]` and so on.

So `arr[i][0]` will be the element at the zeroth index of the respective array

For i=0 ,`arr[0][0]` will be 4 , For i=1 ,`arr[1][0]` will be 13 and so on

Having said that the code can be simplified using array map function and `Math.max`

```js
function myFunc(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(item) {
    return Math.max.apply(null, item)
  })
}

var list = myFunc([
  [4, 5, 1, 3],
  [13, 27, 18, 26],
  [32, 35, 37, 39],
  [1000, 1001, 857, 1]
]);

console.log(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working func:

```js
const myFunc = (arr) => arr.map(innerArray => Math.max(...innerArray));

var list = myFunc([
  [4, 5, 1, 3],
  [13, 27, 18, 26],
  [32, 35, 37, 39],
  [1000, 1001, 857, 1]
]);

console.log(list);
```